# Return value for type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I haven't find anything similar in stackoverflow. I am doing some university stuff, but got stuck with the following.

So I have two types.

```
 type Val = Either Int Bool
 type Env = [(Name, Val)]
```

One of them is understandable. So Env is a list of tupples where the first value of the tupple is a `type Name = String`
But what is up with the type called Val? Like how do I return a value for it?

I have a snippet for something what I would do. But says type error.
Any tips?

```
evalExp :: Exp -> (Env -> Val)   
evalExp exp env = go exp where

  go :: Exp -> Val
  go (IntLit n)  =  n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [**`Either a b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either) has two data constructors: a `Left a`, and a `Right b`.

In this case we use `Either Int Bool`, so we can construct an object with `Left someInt` and `Right someBool`.

Likly the `n` in `IntLit` is an `Int`, so we can return a :

```
go :: Exp -> Val
go (IntLit n) = Left n
```

Comment: Ohh wow. So it's almost like the Either became the constructor  (I know it's not what is happening but an easy way to understand) Many thanks. Now I can work on it! :)

Comment: Its called a Type Constructor.

Answer (score 4):

```hs
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

so `type Val = Either Int Bool` is for *either* `Int` **or** `Bool`

your go would be

```hs
go :: Exp -> Val
go (IntLit n) = Left n
go ...
```